# How can i successfully stop a service using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to stop a service using the following code:

```
    public static void StopService(string name, out string message)
    {
        message = string.Empty;         
        EndTask();

        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
        sc.ServiceName = name;

        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {                               
            try
            {                    
                sc.Stop();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                    
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = $"The service has been stopped.";
        }
    }
```

The EndTask() is defined as follows:

```
    public static void EndTask()
    {
        string taskname = "myservice.exe";
        string processName = taskname.Replace(".exe", "");

        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
```

But I occasionally get the following error

> Cannot stop mytestservice service on computer '.'.
> Inner Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> (0x80004005): The pipe has been ended"

Is this to do with the EndTask routine ? do i need to run the EndTask() asynchronously ?

Comment: you could just kill the process if it does not stop

Comment: The code makes no sense - you kill the process first and then nicely ask it to stop... While it may be somewhat useful in real life there is no point in doing so in code...

Comment: well if i dont kill the process first , i cant stop the service , it always gives an error , cannot stop the service .

Comment: actually i have taken on the  recommendation by @JonathanAlfaro and seems to function as expected.

Comment: Be cautious using `Kill`, _"Data edited by the process or resources allocated to the process can be lost if you call Kill. Kill causes an abnormal process termination and should be used only when necessary."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill

Comment: @Debbie.S I would kill the process only if it fails to stop gracefully.....